# how can get HTML file format as string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, html

I would like to get in javascript the string value of all the content of an html file like:

```
<script>
  var HTMLString = getFile("MyPage.html") //some way to get file as HTML string
</script>
```

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: It cannot be done, since calling another webpage is done in an asyncronous way. So the script won't wait to the response, and the `HTMLString` would be empty.

Answer (score 6):

Try looking into AJAX. Good for implementing HTML and C# into Javascript/web applications.

In your JS file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/mypage.html',
    success: function (file_html) {
        // success
        alert('success : ' + file_html);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

As you want to *get* the file, you could use [`$.get` from jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

```
$.get("/MyPage.html", "", function(data){
  alert('success : ' + data);
  });
```

Just a word of advice: you can only get from the same domain due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

The main *problem* is that the request is done `asyncronously`. This means that the script won't stop, so you don't know at what point the data will be available. This is a change of concept if you come from other static languages, you should pass the function that you want to execute as a callback to jQuery.

Comment: thanks @Francisco, but the function return undefined,

Comment: Updated with explanation of why

Answer (score 3):

as virtually everyone else has pointed out, it's almost always better to do this async, but it's still very possible to do as you have coded using vanilla ajax:

```
var HTMLString = getFile("MyPage.html") //some way to get file as HTML string

alert( HTMLString ); // shows: [html code of the file or 404 page]

function getFile(U) {
    var X = new XMLHttpRequest();
    X.open('GET', U, false);
    X.send();
  return X.responseText;
}
```

again, ajax should be async, but sync is very possible, even across domains using CORS (on plain GETs)...

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the other answers.  I am suspicious why you want to do this.  Never-the-less, here is what you need to do: something along these lines.

```
var script = '<script>\n' +
    '\tvar HTMLString = getFile("MyPage.html"); ' +
    '//some way to get file as HTML string\n' +
    '</' + 'script>';
```

The key part is separating the '</' from the 'script' so HTML doesn't end your code block.