# Client-side rendering of a Markdown file

Tags: markdown, client-side, html-rendering, javascript-marked

One can follow the [Marked library documentation](https://marked.js.org/#usage) and render a Markdown string inline. This is a working code snippet.

```html
<div id="content"></div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML =
      marked.parse('# Hello Ayan \n\nRendered by **marked**.');
  </script>
```

Is there a way to pass a **file** into the `marked.parse` function or through [any other client-side Markdown rendering library](https://byby.dev/js-markdown-libs) and render the **whole file** instead of just a string? I looked into getting the markdown file and passing it as a string. However, I [couldn't find a straightforward way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212027/how-can-get-html-file-format-as-string-in-javascript).

The file is in the same folder as this HTML file and would be served from GitHub using GitHub Pages. However, I could use an absolute link from a CDN if needed. How would I pass the contents to `marked.parse()`? `marked.parse(Hello.md)` didn't work.

Comment: Where would the file come from? Client-side JavaScript doesn't have any way to access the user's filesystem. And if the file is available via HTTP or similar, just retrieve it and pass its contents into `marked.parse()`.

Comment: The file is in the same folder as this HTML file and would be served from GitHub using GitHub Pages. However, I could use an absolute link from a CDN if needed. How would I pass the contents to `marked.parse()`? `marked.parse(Hello.md)` didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The file is in the same folder as this HTML file and would be served from GitHub using GitHub Pages

You can have the browser [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) the content and then pass its content to `marked.parse()`. Something like this should work:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<script>
  fetch("/pages-site/markdown.md")      // The path to the raw Markdown file
    .then(response => response.blob())  // Unwrap to a blob...
    .then(blob => blob.text())          // ...then to raw text...
    .then(markdown => {                 // ...then pass the raw text into marked.parse
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = marked.parse(markdown);
    });
</script>
```

[Here is a live example](https://ccharles.github.io/pages-test/).