# Embed a URL for client-side rendering of a Markdown file

Tags: markdown, url-parameters, html-rendering, javascript-marked, client-side-rendering

One can [render a Markdown file on a static site client-side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70160293/2748772) using the code below.

```html
<div id="txt"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<script>
  fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ccharles/pages-test/master/markdown.md")
      .then(r=>r.blob()).then(b=>b.text()).then(m=>{document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML=marked.parse(m)})
</script>
```

I found there are [two ways to embed a URL in another URL](https://s7ng6n.medium.com/how-to-embed-a-url-in-another-url-19c5ca4a89fe). However, I couldn't figure out [how to pass the Markdown file URL as a parameter to the Marked.js URL](https://marked.js.org/using_advanced#options). Can one add a Markdown file URL to the `GET` parameter of a library URL to render Markdown to HTML client side using this or [any other library](https://openbase.com/categories/js/best-javascript-client-markdown-rendering-libraries?vs=marked%2Creact-markdown%2Cngx-markdown)? Something like this..

`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js?MDUri=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ccharles/pages-test/master/markdown.md`

@chris

Comment: There is Docsify-This, for example https://docsify-this.net/?basePath=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ccharles/pages-test/master/&homepage=markdown.md&hide-credits=true#/. See https://docsify-this.net/#/ for documentation.

Comment: Yes, that works, @Marijn. Please post it as an answer. I'll use it if this can't be done with other popular libraries.

Comment: Your question is a resource request, which is off-topic (because the answers are invalidated when the resource is no longer available) so it's better not to post an answer I think.

Comment: I wish there were a [browser flag for Markdown](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1550904). Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One needs a domain to serve the code that would parse the Markdown file client side. One example of that is Docsify. PFB example

[Published by Docsify-This](https://docsify-this.net/?basePath=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ayanmullick/test/master/testfolder&homepage=StachExgMdScript.md#/)

However, Docsify doesn't render the script tag in one's Markdown file. So one can serve code similar to snippet below and serve it from their own GitHub repository after [enabling GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/quickstart#creating-your-website).

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ayanmullick/test/master/testfolder/StachExgMdScript.md")
        .then((response) => response.text()) // Unwrap to a blob...
        .then((markdown) => {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = marked.parse(markdown);
            var scriptTags = document.querySelectorAll("#content script");
            function handleDocumentWrite(content) {
                var contentPlaceholder = document.getElementById("content");
                contentPlaceholder.innerHTML += content}
            window.document.write = handleDocumentWrite;
            scriptTags.forEach(function(scriptTag) {
                if (scriptTag.src) {
                    var externalScript = document.createElement("script");
                    externalScript.src = scriptTag.src;
                    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(externalScript);
                } else {eval(scriptTag.innerText); }
            });
        });
});
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
```

[Example link](https://ayanmullick.github.io/AzIaaS/?path=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ayanmullick/test/master/testfolder/StachExgMdScript.md)